# MSoffice (source) to Azure Data Factory Gen2 (Sink) connection issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I am trying to Connect my pipeline to Azure Data Storage Gen2. The Test Connection is successful when using **Account Key** to connect, but as i am importing from **MS 365**, Only **Service Principal ID & Key are supported** as shown in the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqwVK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOm37.png)

When it comes to Service Principal ID & Key for **Azure Blob storage** (Azure Data Storage Gen2), this is what i can't find in Enterprise applications,idk if it with another name in the applications or some other issue, hence can't sink my pipeline.

I did not create an Enterprise Application for the storage myself (it auto created). I can't find the service principal that belongs to this Azure Data Storage Gen2 i am trying to sink to. And being a MS application, i cant delete the app, and if i want to make a new application for Storage Gen2, it wont let me because...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukcK0.png)

I tried using all other Authentication types, none is working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

To create ADLS Gen2 linked service with service principal authentication Add `storage blob data contributor role` to the storage account by select IAM and click on Add and select `Add role assignment`

[image]

Select the `user or group` option and click on `select memeber` Option and selected the SPN and click on `Review +Assign` Option

[image]

created a linked service of ADLS Gen2 in in ADF with  `TenantId`, `ClientId`,`Secret` values and `To linked service` as `Test connection` option. It tested successfully.

[image]

Create a dataset with above linked service and use it as sink.